# Trying to Calculate value in table row react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have built a table over here, in which user can enter values in 1st three columns and next 4 get's auto filled. I am able to generated 1st two values by calculations but stuck with the next 2 col's. Formula for viscosity and shear rate you can see in the handleFormSubmit function.
The formula for Absolute Drop is above row viscocity minus current row that's why 1st row's Absolute Drop will be null and 2nd rows will be 1st row's visocisity minus 2nd row's viscosity and so on.
The formula for %Drop will be similar ((1st row's visocisity minus 2nd row's viscosity) * 100)/ 1st row's viscosity.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  const row1 = [];
  const [row, setRow] = useState();
  const [NewRow, setNewRow] = useState([]);
  const [NewRow2, setNewRow2] = useState([0,1,2,3,4]);
  const [allRowsAdded, updateAllRows] = useState(0);
  const [viscosity, setViscosity] = useState([]);

  const [IntensificationRatio, setIntensificationRatio] = useState()
  const [editFormData, setEditFormData] = useState({
    Injection_Speed: "",
    Fill_Time: "",
    Peak_Inj_Press: "",
    Viscosity: "",
    Shear_Rate: "",
    Absolute_Drop_Viscosity: ""
  })
  const [isRowId, setIsRowId] = useState(null)

  const handleEditFormChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute("name");
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    const newFormData = { ...editFormData };
    newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;

    setEditFormData(newFormData);
  }

  const handleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const editedValue = {
        id: isRowId,
        Injection_Speed: editFormData.Injection_Speed,
        Fill_Time: editFormData.Fill_Time,
        Peak_Inj_Press: editFormData.Peak_Inj_Press,
        Viscosity: editFormData.Fill_Time * editFormData.Peak_Inj_Press * IntensificationRatio,
        Shear_Rate: 1 / editFormData.Fill_Time
      }

      const newValues = [...NewRow2];

      const index = NewRow2.findIndex((value) => value === isRowId)

      newValues[index] = editedValue;
      
      setNewRow2(newValues);
  }

  const addRow = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRow(e.target.value);
  };

  const increaseRow = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(row); i++) {
      row1[i] = allRowsAdded + i;
    }
    updateAllRows((allRowsAdded) => allRowsAdded + parseInt(row));
    setNewRow([...NewRow, ...row1]);

  };

  const deleteRow = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = [...NewRow].filter((rowId) => {
      return rowId !== id;
    });
    setNewRow(updatedRows);
  };

  const deleteRow2 = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = [...NewRow2].filter((rowId) => {
      return rowId !== id;
    });
    setNewRow2(updatedRows);
  };

  const demo = (id) => {
    setIsRowId(id)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" onChange={addRow} placeholder="Enter Number Of Row's" /><br />
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setIntensificationRatio(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter Intensification Ratio" />
        </form>
        <button onClick={increaseRow}> Add </button>


      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={handleEditFormSubmit} >
          <Table striped bordered hover responsive variant="light">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Injection Speed </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Fill Time </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Peak Inj Press </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Viscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Shear Rate </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> AbsoluteDropViscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> %DropViscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Action </h6>{" "}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="grid_style">
              {NewRow2.map((element, rowId) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={rowId}>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={element.Injection_Speed} name="Injection_Speed" onChange={handleEditFormChange} onClick={() => demo(rowId)} /> </td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={element.Fill_Time} name="Fill_Time" onChange={handleEditFormChange} onClick={() => demo(rowId)}/></td>

                    <td><input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={element.Peak_Inj_Press} name="Peak_Inj_Press" onChange={handleEditFormChange} onClick={() => demo(rowId)}/> </td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" name="Viscosity" value={isNaN(Math.round(element.Viscosity)) ? '-' : Math.round(element.Viscosity) } onChange={handleEditFormChange} onClick={() => demo(rowId)} readOnly/> </td>

                    <td>  <input type='text' className="form-control" name="Shear_Rate" value={isNaN(Number(element.Shear_Rate).toFixed(3)) ? '-' : Number(element.Shear_Rate).toFixed(3)} readOnly /> </td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" readOnly /></td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" readOnly /></td>

                    <td> <i className="fa fa-trash viscocity_icons" onClick={() => deleteRow2(element)}></i> </td>
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
              {NewRow.map((rowId) => {
              return (
                <tr key={rowId}>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" readOnly />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <i
                      className="fa fa-trash viscocity_icons"
                      onClick={() => deleteRow(rowId)}
                    >
                    </i>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
          <button type="submit"> Calculate </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-torvalds-jj3h2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use an array and save your data into that array:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
const rowData = {
    Injection_Speed: "",
    Fill_Time: "",
    Peak_Inj_Press: "",
    Viscosity: "",
    Shear_Rate: "",
    Absolute_Drop_Viscosity: ""
};
const App = () => {
  const [row, setRow] = useState();
  const [allRowsAdded, updateAllRows] = useState(0);
  const [viscosity, setViscosity] = useState([]);

  const [IntensificationRatio, setIntensificationRatio] = useState(1)
  const [editFormData, setEditFormData] = useState([rowData])
  const [isRowId, setIsRowId] = useState(null)

  const handleEditFormChange = (event, fieldName, index) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    setEditFormData(prevState => {
        const newState = [...prevState];
        newState[index][fieldName] = fieldValue;
        return newState;
    })
  }

  const handleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      setEditFormData(prevState => {
        const newState = [...prevState];
        newState.map(item => {
            let viscosity = item['Fill_Time'] * item['Peak_Inj_Press'] * IntensificationRatio;
            viscosity = isNaN(Math.round(viscosity)) ? '-' : Math.round(viscosity)
            let shearRate = 1 / item['Fill_Time'];
            shearRate = isNaN(Number(shearRate).toFixed(3)) ? '-' : Number(shearRate).toFixed(3)
            item.Viscosity = viscosity;
            item.Shear_Rate = shearRate;
        })
        return newState;
      });
  }

  const addRow = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRow(e.target.value);
  };

  const increaseRow = () => {
    setEditFormData(prevState => {
        const newState = [...prevState];
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(row); i++) {
            newState.push(rowData);
        }
        return newState;
    })
  };

  const deleteRow = (key) => {
    setEditFormData(prevState => {
        const newState = prevState.splice(key, 1);
        return newState;
    })
  };

  const demo = (id) => {
    setIsRowId(id)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" onChange={addRow} placeholder="Enter Number Of Row's" /><br />
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setIntensificationRatio(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter Intensification Ratio" />
        </form>
        <button onClick={increaseRow}> Add </button>
      </div>

      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={handleEditFormSubmit} >
          <Table striped bordered hover responsive variant="light">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Injection Speed </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Fill Time </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Peak Inj Press </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Viscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Shear Rate </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> AbsoluteDropViscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> %DropViscocity </h6>{" "}
                </th>
                <th>
                  {" "}
                  <h6> Action </h6>{" "}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="grid_style">
              {editFormData.map((element, rowId) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={rowId}>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={element.Injection_Speed} onChange={e => handleEditFormChange(e, 'Injection_Speed',rowId)} onClick={() => demo(rowId)} /> </td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={element.Fill_Time} onChange={e => handleEditFormChange(e,'Fill_Time',rowId)} onClick={() => demo(rowId)}/></td>

                    <td><input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={element.Peak_Inj_Press} onChange={e => handleEditFormChange(e, 'Peak_Inj_Press',rowId)} onClick={() => demo(rowId)}/> </td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" value={element.Viscosity } onChange={e => handleEditFormChange(e,rowId)} onClick={() => demo(rowId)} readOnly/> </td>

                    <td>  <input type='text' className="form-control" value={element.Shear_Rate} readOnly /> </td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" readOnly /></td>

                    <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" readOnly /></td>

                    <td> <i className="fa fa-trash viscocity_icons" onClick={() => deleteRow(element, rowId)}></i> </td>
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
          <button type="submit"> Calculate </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-field-8ktxz?file=/src/App.js